# LinkedList void from firebase

Tags: android, firebase, linked-list, firebase-realtime-database

I use firebase for backend of my application, but I have this problem: in the ValueEventListener my list is not empty but when I use getting methods it is empty and I don't understand why.
This is my code:

```
    import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.LinkedList;

import it.unisalento.progetto.software.cunamameli.myapplication.Machine.Model.Machine;

/**
 * Created by marcomameli on 19/09/16.
 */
public class MachineDB {

    private final static String TAG = "MachineDB";

    private FirebaseDatabase database;
    private DatabaseReference mMachineRefence;
    private LinkedList<Machine> mMachines;
    private LinkedList<MarkerOptions> mMachineMarkers;

    public MachineDB(){
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMachineRefence = database.getReference().child("machines");
        mMachines = new LinkedList<>();
        mMachineMarkers = new LinkedList<>();
        ValueEventListener machinesListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    Machine machine = child.getValue(Machine.class);
                    mMachines.add(machine);
                    //Log.d(TAG + " Macine clas",""+machine.gps.coordinates);
                    LatLng machineposition = new LatLng(machine.gps.coordinates.get(0),machine.gps.coordinates.get(1));
                    //Log.d(TAG + "LatLng",""+machineposition);
                    MarkerOptions myMarkerPosition = new MarkerOptions().position(machineposition);
                    //Log.d(TAG + " position",""+myMarkerPosition.getPosition());
                    mMachineMarkers.add(myMarkerPosition);
                    Log.d(TAG + " MarkerList",""+mMachineMarkers.isEmpty()); // here it is not empty
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Impossibile riceve i dati dal database");
            }
        };
        mMachineRefence.addValueEventListener(machinesListener);

        Log.d(TAG + "afterdb",""+mMachines.isEmpty()); // here is empty
    }

    public LinkedList<Machine> getmMachines() {
        return mMachines;
    }

    public LinkedList<MarkerOptions> getmMachineMarkers() {
        Log.d(TAG + " getting",""+mMachineMarkers.isEmpty()); // here it is empty
        return mMachineMarkers;
    }
}
```

Where is the error?

Comment: This looks like the basic asynchronous problem to me: All firebase operations are asynchronous meaning your program won't wait till it received the data from firebase before it goes to the next statement in your code.

Comment: Ok I think this is the problem, can you have a solution?

Comment: Depends on your goal. If you want to keep track of changes you could call your get methodes every second or so.

Comment: I find a solution using firebaseRecyclerAdapter